# ALL input doesn't work

Tags: 7, uri

I installed Drupal on my VPS, but it seems that all input on website doesn't work from web interface. What I mean by that:

- I cannot login by using web interface
- I CAN login by using one-time login link generated by Drush, but then strange things happen, I guess consequences of not working input - like Admin Menu disappears after refresh, and editing any content is impossible, after sending change - the edit page simply refresh with old values,
- I have Redmine installed on this server and it works ok, so it seems to be Drupal specific.
- The problem doesn't exist with "?q=/user/login" - it exists only with rewritten links. I'm pretty sure I have unmodified .htaccess.
- The problem exists when I remove from .htaccess everything, with the exception of: `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php` and `RewriteEngine on` (which is bare minimum for rewriting to work it seems).
- There are absolutely **no errors** in logs of Drupal, Apache and MySQL.

My Virtual Host: http://pastebin.com/R5hRQMWc

My .htaccess: http://pastebin.com/xM5Kj1yd

System: Ubuntu 14.04, Apache 2.4.7, PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.2 , mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.37

Any ideas what is going on and why only Drupal is affected?

Comment: _I'm pretty sure I have unmodified .htaccess_, then _The problem exists when I remove from .htaccess everything_. So you have or you haven't modified .htaccess, which is it? ;)

Comment: This website have few months, when you are busy, after few months you are not sure of anything ;) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Apache server doesn't include "mod_rewrite".

Try do below code in the console:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 reload
```

I think this help to you!

Comment: Wow, that was it! I didn't think about it for a moment, because "pretty urls" were actually working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Check that mod_rewrite is enabled by going to ?q=admin/reports/status/php and searching for mod_rewrite. If it isn't in the list of "loaded modules", ssh into your server and do "sudo a2enmod rewrite", and then "sudo service apache2 restart".
2. If that didn't help, go to /etc/apache2/sites-available and locate and edit the .conf file for your site. using, say "vi FILENAME.conf". Make sure it contains something like:

`<Directory /path/to/drupal>

 AllowOverride All
 Order allow,deny
 allow from all
</Directory>`

If you change the .conf file, you'll have to restart apache again, to make it take effect.